# Finding syntax error in code php/drupal

Tags: php

I'm stuck... could someone help me find the syntax error on this line of code? I'm new to PHP and i'm stuck with it!

```
<?php isset($node->field_artistname['und']) { echo $node->field_artistname['und'][0]['value']; }?>
```

Comment: where is `if()` for `isset()`

Comment: Please provide full code with error you getting.

Comment: is there no more before before `field_artistname`??

Comment: Can you post the exact, full error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `if()` for `isset()`

```
 <?php if(isset($node->field_artistname['und']))
       {  
            echo $node->field_artistname['und'][0]['value']; 
       }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be your answer.

```
 if(isset($node->field_artistname['und'])) { 
     echo $node->field_artistname['und'][0]['value']; 
 }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stay with the one liner use this.

```
<?php echo isset($node->field_artistname['und']) ?$node->field_artistname['und'][0]['value']:""; ?>
```